# Draw a circle filled with random color sqares on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got pretty strange example to work on...
I need to fill a circle with 1x1 pixels, all with different colors in a browser.

What I tried, is something like this

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

function createRandomSqaure(destination) {
    var size = destination.height() * destination.width();

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
        destination.append('<div class="pixel" style="background: ' + getRandomColor() + '"></div>');
    }
}

createRandomSqaure($('.pic'));
```

The case is, it super slow (as you can imagine, loop goes 40k times for 200x200 image), I thought maybe a better way will be drawing It on canvas?
And I need to draw a circle filled with this pixels in the end...

I don't know how to do something like this in a more optimal way, I can use a nodejs server also, but I think generating something like this server side on heroku is a way too much.

I'm just curious what do you guys think, and what is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a simple approach like this:

- Draw all the pixels with random colors in a 200x200 grid on a canvas
- Change composite mode
- Draw circle on top

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/fBv86/)

**Results in:**

[image]

**Example:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), // get canvas element
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),              // get context
    x, y = 0,                                   // initialize
    dia = canvas.width,
    radius = dia * 0.5;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);                        // to make pixels sharper

for(; y < dia; y++) {                           // walk x/y grid
    for(x = 0; x < dia; x++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = getRndColor();          // set random color
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);               // draw a pixel
    }
}

// create circle

// removes pixels outside next shape
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'; 
ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

// reset
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; 

function getRndColor() {
    var r = 255*Math.random()|0,
        g = 255*Math.random()|0,
        b = 255*Math.random()|0;
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, with a better solution. Way to go :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, certainly, adding 40000 divs is very slow, and should always be avoided. Tricks like this one were used in the old ways to get dynamic round corners on divs, and it made the page incredibly slower.

So yes, you should use canvas. By the way, you could optimise the way you get a random color:

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.Random()* 256);
var g = Math.floor(Math.Random()* 256);
var b = Math.floor(Math.Random()* 256);

var cssColor = 'rgb(' + r +', ' + g + ',' + b +')';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would def use canvas for this, because you are adding tons of overhead by using actual DOM elements.

```
function drawRect(x,y) {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(x,y,1,1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = getRandomColor();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Its still going to be sucky, but its sucky no matter what unless you have a server generate images or something before hand so the client doesn't get tied up.