# Generate Infinite Colors for Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, colors

I want to create an array full of random colors, that will never run out to generate random balls with random colors. So instead of having only 5 colors (blue, red, green, yellow, white) to choose from I want a different color for every ball.

[whole code:](https://jsfiddle.net/0yx4ca98/)

I have already tried:

```
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

Here I only get one random color for every ball. And I have also used loops already which is probably the right answer but I just implemented it wrongfully.

JS:

```
var ballArray = [];
var colorArray = ['blue','red','green','yellow','white'];
var gravity = 0.9;

function drawBall() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ballArray.length; i++) {
        var ball = ballArray[i];
        ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        
        ball.x += ball.xd;
        if (ball.x + ball.radius > screenWidth || ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
            ball.xd *= -1;
        }
```

Comment: See the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237497/draw-a-circle-filled-with-random-color-sqares-on-canvas to get random colours. You don't need an array of colours, just create a random one each time your create a new bubble.

Comment: I do have random colors now but when updating the position of the ball it just sets the ball to a new random color so I'm pretty sure that I need a colorArray.  Code: https://jsfiddle.net/0yx4ca98/1/ Make sure to click once on the screen to see the resulting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your `randomColor` directly, replace

```
this.color = colorArray[randomNumber(0, colorArray.length - 1)];
```

with

```
this.color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you want each ball to have a different random color without the color repetition? Or just fix the second JSFiddle code to generate balls with random numbers without the flickering?

If you want to have a **unique color for each ball**, you can store already used colors in an array and check whether newly generated color is included in the array. For that, I would use this code:

```
var ballArray = [];
var usedColors = [];
var gravity = 0.9;

function generateNewColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var colorIncluded = true;

      while (colorIncluded == true) {
        var color = '#';
        // generate new color
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        // check if the color is already used
        var used = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < usedColors.length; i++){
          if(usedColors[i] == color){
            used = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(!used){ break; }
      }
      usedColors.push(color);
      return color;
}
```

Nevertheless this method is not very effective for a large amount of generated balls.

**To fix the flickering** in your code, just erase the function that returns a random number in a Ball() function:

```
this.color = getRndColor();
```

And use the generated color in a drawBall() function:

```
ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Jerry! Only feedback I would give is to avoid asking for clarification on the question within the answer itself, rather comment under the question and then word each answer you give to align with each interpretation. i.e. if x do y, if z do b

Comment: Thank you Zach, I appreciate your feedback. I wanted to write a comment under the question but I don't have enough reputation for that.